# Flutter how to use Lists to create similar widgets white implicit-case and implicity-dynamic set to false

Tags: flutter, dart, types, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to be better about typing in flutter/dart. To force this, I made an analysis_options.yaml with:

```
 analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

and that works great, but I have a hard time with code like the following:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      children: [...widgetList()]);
  }

  widgetList(){
     List<Map<String,dynamic>> defineWidgets = [
      {"text":"beer", "color": Colors.blue}, // <-- Missing type arguments for map literal. Try adding an explicit type like 'dynamic' or enable implicit dynamic in your analysis options.
      {"text":"wine", "color": Colors.red},
    ];
    List<Widget> finalWidgets =[];
    for(int i = 0; i < defineWidgets.length; i++ ){
      finalWidgets.add(
        Expanded(child:Container(
          child:Text(defineWidgets[i]['text']), // <-- the argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
          color:defineWidgets[i]['color']
        ))
      );
    }
    return finalWidgets;
  }
```

I tried using cast() to no avail.
Is there a way to do this of function without setting implicit-casts and implicit-dynamic to true?

Comment: The first lint is asking you to do: `<String, dynamic>{key1: value1, key2: value2}` for each of your `Map` literals.  The second is telling you to use an explicit cast (i.e., `defineWidgets[i]['text'] as String`).

Comment: that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error "Missing type arguments for map literal. Try adding an explicit type like 'dynamic' or enable implicit dynamic in your analysis options." seems to require you to cast `<String,dynamic>` on each Map entry for `defineWidgets`. Though the code you've provided seems to work fine on DartPad. The declaration could look something similar to.

```dart
List<Map<String,dynamic>> pricing = [
  <String, dynamic>{"name":"beer", "price": 5},
  <String, dynamic>{"name":"wine", "price": 10},
];
  
for(Map<String,dynamic> product in pricing){
  print('${product['name']} Price: ${product['price']}');
}
```

As for `Text(defineWidgets[i]['text'])`, the Widget can only handle String value. But since we're fetching a dynamic value from `Map<String, dynamic>`, we need to cast the value as a String for the Widget to know that value is indeed a String.

```dart
`Text(defineWidgets[i]['text'] as String)`
```